# Re-reading a file using Random Access

Tags: java, file, random-access

I want to re-read a file by adding data to the file when it reaches EOF. But second read after  adding data isn't working.

This is my code

```
       File f = new File("sample.csv");
       byte[] bb= new byte[(int)f.length()];
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile (f, "r");
      int bytesread=0;
      bytesread = raf.read(bb, 0,(int)f.length());
              //bytesread =302 or something

      raf.seek(f.length());
      Thread.sleep(4000);
      bytesread = raf.read(bb,0,2); 
    //bytesread = -1 instead of 2  
      raf.close();
```

What I'm doing is initially i'm reading the contents of the file, during the first read say
my  bytesread = 302 or something. Now Seeking the pointer to EOF and adding some data to my file and reading it again but instead of desired result bytesread =2, I'm getting bytesread as -1. Can anyone tell me what is the prob with my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most streams, once you read the end of the file, you can't read again (RandomAccessFIle might be different but I suspect not)

What I would do is only read up to, but not including the end of the file, which works of other streams.

e.g.

```
int positionToRead = ...
int length = f.length();
// only read the bytes which are there.
int bytesRead = f.read(bb, 0, length - positionToRead);
```

This should work repeatedly.

Comment: Fine Peter, I get your point but no other way to read the file after EOF if data is added?

Comment: With RandomAccessFile it would make sense, but I don't know what it is. I would check the Javadocs to see if there is such a method to "reset" the end of file. Perhaps all you need to do is call seek() ??

Comment: I checked there are no such methods to reset EOF. Ya seek() only sets the file pointer offset.

Comment: True, but is you seek where the end of file was, does this allow the read to proceed?

Comment: Yes I seek EOF, but it doesn't allow read to proceed. but it reads fine if I do this seek(f.length()-2) & read(bb,0,2). As you've said, once I reach EOF I'm not able to read additional data which has been appended.

Comment: Hey Peter, I've fixed my code, culprit is my Textedit application which I used to add extra data in the .csv file, instead I used an xls doc instead of text editor, my code worked fine.